# remember mutableStateOf cannot serve as a delegate

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-tabs

I'm trying to implement tabs with Composable and was following this tutorial: [How to Create Tabs in Jetpack Compose](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/tabs-in-jetpack-compose/). This line (inside a Composable function) produces the following error:

```
var tabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
```

> Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate

Why? I don't understand the error.

I found another tutorial: [Jetpack Compose — Top Tabs](https://medium.com/@maheshgubbi/jetpack-compose-top-tabs-4f21266b39a5), but it's incomplete unfortunately. Every code snippet uses a variable `pagerState`, that is nowhere defined. Furthermore, [Pager Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/pager) is experimental and I don't really need the pager functionality anyway.